# Ubuntu is crashing for no reason on my 2 in 1 Asus Laptop

Tags: freeze, crash

The other day I was bored and decided to flash Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop. However, ever since then it's been crashing without a rhyme or reason. Attached is the about computer screen. What logs should I provide? Important, system or all? I'm curious on if it could be a Wayland issue. I'm kind of new to Linux, so I don't know if that could be causing issues with my computer. I just switched to Xorg just in case.

Switching did not fix it. When I tried typing on my tablet the screen went black and I had to hard shutdown.

```
 5:09:11 PM kernel: i2c i2c-4: i2c write failed: -121
 4:56:40 PM systemd: Failed to start Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
 4:56:39 PM kernel: i2c i2c-4: i2c write failed: -121
 4:56:39 PM kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_isr: failed backplane access
 4:33:10 PM kernel: i2c i2c-4: i2c write failed: -121
 2:53:07 PM gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 2:53:03 PM systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
 2:53:03 PM systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
 2:53:03 PM systemd: Failed to start Sound Service.
 2:53:02 PM systemd: Failed to start Sound Service.
 2:53:02 PM systemd: Failed to start Sound Service.
 2:53:01 PM systemd: Failed to start Sound Service.
 2:53:01 PM systemd: Failed to start Sound Service.
 2:53:00 PM systemd: Failed to start Sound Service.
 2:52:59 PM systemd: Failed to start Sound Service.
 2:52:56 PM gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
 2:51:11 PM systemd: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
 2:51:04 PM gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
 2:51:01 PM kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
 2:51:00 PM kernel: ================================================================================
 2:51:00 PM kernel: shift exponent 16384 is too large for 32-bit type 'unsigned int'
 2:51:00 PM kernel: UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-WLUive/linux-5.15.0/sound/soc/soc-dapm.c:3429:23
 2:51:00 PM kernel: ================================================================================
 2:51:00 PM kernel: shift exponent 16384 is too large for 32-bit type 'unsigned int'
 2:51:00 PM kernel: UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-WLUive/linux-5.15.0/sound/soc/soc-dapm.c:3411:51
 2:51:00 PM kernel: ================================================================================
 2:51:00 PM kernel: shift exponent 16384 is too large for 32-bit type 'unsigned int'
 2:51:00 PM kernel: UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-WLUive/linux-5.15.0/sound/soc/soc-dapm.c:3409:15
 2:51:00 PM kernel: ================================================================================
 2:51:00 PM kernel: shift exponent 16384 is too large for 32-bit type 'unsigned int'
 2:51:00 PM kernel: UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-WLUive/linux-5.15.0/sound/soc/soc-dapm.c:3408:13
 2:51:00 PM kernel: ================================================================================
 2:51:00 PM kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43340/2 wl0: Apr 23 2021 05:48:34 version 6.10.190.91 (r728536) FWID 01-d45e96c4
 2:51:00 PM kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
 2:50:59 PM kernel: ================================================================================
 2:50:59 PM kernel: shift exponent 16384 is too large for 32-bit type 'unsigned int'
 2:50:59 PM kernel: UBSAN: shift-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-WLUive/linux-5.15.0/sound/soc/soc-dapm.c:810:15
 2:50:59 PM kernel: ================================================================================
 2:50:58 PM kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
 2:50:58 PM kernel: atomisp-isp2 0000:00:03.0: Support for Cherrytrail (ISP2401) was disabled at compile time
 2:50:56 PM kernel: mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
 2:50:56 PM kernel: ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PCI0.I2C3.TIDR (20210730/dspkginit-438)
```

Comment: What is the hardware? What is the GPU?

Comment: @pilot6 Sorry I thought the picture attached. It's a Intel atom x5- z8500 1.44 GHz 4 core. Mesa Intel HD graphics CHV

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting